# How can i refresh the widget on the the page A, when i return from page B?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a stateful Page A that contains a widget which is present in a seperate stateful class.

The widget fetches a number from sharedPreferences in its initState method and show it and when i click on the widget, it routes to Page B, Page B contains a function that change the number in the sharedPreferences.

when i go back i dont see the changes but when i reopen the app or switch to a different tab and come back, i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page A, when you go to page B use,

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/pageB").then((value) {
  if (value == true) {
    setState(() {
      // refresh page 1 here, you may want to reload your SharedPreferences here according to your needs
    });
  }
});
```

In page B, when you want to go back to page A, use

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

---

**Edit**: If you don't have a named route, you may want to use following in 1st situation.

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageB())).then((value) {
  if (value == true) {
    setState(() {
      // refresh page 1 here, you may want to reload your SharedPreferences here according to your needs
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: just found a nice place to put  `Navigator.pop(context, true);` , Using it with `WillPopScope`' inside its property `onWillPop` makes sure that whenever the page B is popped using any means like back button, back arrow etc, the widget is always updated.

Comment: Yes, you can put it there, it all depends on your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving from pageA to pageB:

In pageA widget button click you need to call the below code:

```
_navigateAndDisplayData(
      BuildContext context) async {
    final returnVal = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageB()),
    );

    setState(() {
      // returnVal has true or false.
      if (returnVal){
         // Put your code here
       }

    });
  }
```

If you always refresh with expecting any value from pageB. Then just remove the if statement.

On other side pageB you want to send the data on pageA just used

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```